# developer manuals

Tags: c#, automation, manual

My team and I are in the final phase of our software development project.
We are using Visual Studio to compile our project and coding in C#.
We need to build user manuals. Is there any way to generate user manuals from the comments of the application and code?

Comment: Is the user an end-user or a developer? (Are you writing a library or a GUI?)

Comment: If you think that your users need to know what's going on inside your code then I really hope your users either: never need to read the manuals (god forbid if they did), or, have access to the source code and 5 years programming experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have commented your code appropriately there are a number of third-party tools that you can use to generate documentation.

The following list is not exhaustive:

- [SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)
- [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)
- [Doc-O-Matic](http://www.doc-o-matic.com/)
- [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html)
- [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)
- ...

I just hope your end-users are developers and you are writing some sort of API. These sort of documentation generation tool are usually only suited for internal use or external developers for which you created an API that they can use.

Comment: thanks actually meant developer manual, your links were very helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

If your target audience was other developers, you could do something like what is mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759714/extracting-doc-comments-from-c-source-file) but if it is end users who aren't developers, then it isn't likely that the comments in your code are going to be all that useful to them, and if they are... then they probably aren't all that useful to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using XML Documentation Commments...you could use the `/doc` compile option.

[XML Documentation Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments)

> When you compile with the /doc option, the compiler will search for
>   all XML tags in the source code and create an XML documentation file.
>   To create the final documentation based on the compiler-generated
>   file, you can create a custom tool or use a tool such as DocFX or
>   Sandcastle.